# Возведение матрицы в очень большую степень

Tags: java

Добрый день.
Пишу код, считающий остаток от деления числа Фибоначчи через матрицы.
На малых n с long'ами всё работало, когда перешёл к BigInteger, всё крашится.

Выдаёт:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Вроде всё инициализировано, никак не пойму, в чём проблема. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема.
Вот код: http://pastebin.com/Q63qdVRW

Comment: приложите трейс ошибки и кодом к вопрому, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

проблема в следующем участке кода

```
BigInteger[][] mResult = new BigInteger[mRRowLength][mRColLength];
        for(int i = 0; i < mRRowLength; i++) {         // rows from m1
            for(int j = 0; j < mRColLength; j++) {     // columns from m2
                for(int k = 0; k < m1ColLength; k++) { // columns from m1
                    mResult[i][j] = mResult[i][j].add(m1[i][k].multiply(m2[k][j]));
                }
            }
        }
```

инициализировали ТОЛЬКО массив mResult, а элементы - нет.
пробегаемся по циклу и обращаемся к элементам mResult.

`mResult[i][j].add(m1[i][k].multiply(m2[k]` - вот тут хотим для элементов массива присвоить некое значение, только вот `mResult[i][j]`== null, поэтому и получаем `NullPointerException`

Comment: cпасибо. У меня ощущение, что я совсем тупой. Не совсем понял, а как в таком случае инициализировать элементы?

Comment: @TheDocto нет, 0 нельзя, так как операция умножения. по смыслу получается, что должно быть  `mResult[i][j] = m1[i][k].multiply(m2[k][j]));`

Comment: @Senior Pomidor, большое спасибо за разъяснения, всё, понял!